# Error whilst running a state space equation using python GEKKO library

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gekko

Attempting to model thermal losses from a building, I have implemented the following code to run the model using a state-space equation. It seems to take in variables as expected from .csv files and arrange them into correctly formed matrices. However, it is returning `"Exception: Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems"`.
When trying to debug I printed all the matrices in the equations to see if they matched (see below). I feel like this should be easy to see but I don't know where I have gone wrong.

```
[[-9.15750916  9.15750916]
 [-0.12465719  0.13056645]]
[[295]
 [295]]
[[0.00000000e+00 7.38461538e+00 3.84615385e+00]
 [5.90925744e-03 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
[[[21.  14.  23.  28.  19. ]]

 [[ 1.5  1.2  1.4  1.7  2. ]]

 [[ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0. ]]]
[[1 0]]
```

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
# SYSTEM BOUNDARIES
comfort = {'Occupied': np.array([20, 24])+273.15, \
           'Unoccupied': np.array([18, 26])+273.15}  
build_type = {'detached':np.array([0.42,0.26,8.86,19.1,1.92]),\
             'semi-detached':np.array([]),\
             'end-terrace':np.array([]),\
             'mid-terrace':np.array([]),\
             'bungalow':np.array([]),\
             'flat':np.array([])}
# get csv data
# datafile = ""
df = pd.read_csv(r"COP_test.csv")
# sort data by column names
x0 = np.array(df["Ta"]) # Ambient temp
x1 = np.array(df["Ih"]) # Solar radiation
x2 = np.array(df["Qo"]) # Additional heating influences
#GEKKO model and initialise model simulator
m = GEKKO(remote=False); m.options.IMODE=4
# Building temperature variables
T_int = m.FV(295, lb=18+273.15, ub=24+273.15)
T_wal = m.FV(295, lb=15+273.15, ub=30+273.15)
# independent variables
Q_ext = m.Array(m.Param,3); Q_ext[0].value=x0; Q_ext[1].value=x1; Q_ext[2].value=x2, 
# building coefficients
R_int, C_int, R_wal, C_wal, gA = build_type[btype]
# Matrix equations
A = np.array([[-1/(R_int*C_int), 1/(R_int*C_int)],
              [-1/(R_int*C_wal), -(-1/(R_wal*C_wal)-1/(R_int*C_wal))]])
Bc = 1/C_int
Bx = np.array([[0, gA/C_int, 1/C_int],
              [1/(R_wal*C_wal), 0, 0]])
C = np.array([[1, 0]])
# [T_int.dt(), T_wal.dt()] = m.equations()
x, y, u = m.state_space(A,Bx,C,D=None,discrete=True)
# right now does not include Bc, could append into matrix Bx
u[0].value = np.array([[x0],[x1],[x2]])
x[0].value = np.array([[T_int],[T_wal]])
print(A, x[0].value, Bx, u[0].value, C, sep='\n')
m.time = np.linspace(0,24,len(x0)) # time points, ideally to have a reading every half hour
m.options.nodes = 4
m.solve() # (GUI=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needed some modifications to import the data but the model was good. The script was also missing the data file and the `btype` variable. Here is some sample data for testing with `data.csv`.

```
time,Ta,Ih,Qo
0,30,0,0
4,31,0,0
8,35,10,20
12,38,20,30
16,40,50,20
20,37,30,10
24,30,0,0
```

On future questions, please include a complete example. Here is the modified code. I've commented out the state constraints because those can lead to an infeasible solution. You also need to use `m.options.NODES=2` for discrete state space models.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
# SYSTEM BOUNDARIES
comfort = {'Occupied': np.array([20, 24])+273.15, \
           'Unoccupied': np.array([18, 26])+273.15}  
build_type = {'detached':np.array([0.42,0.26,8.86,19.1,1.92]),\
             'semi-detached':np.array([]),\
             'end-terrace':np.array([]),\
             'mid-terrace':np.array([]),\
             'bungalow':np.array([]),\
             'flat':np.array([])}
# get csv data
df = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv")
btype = 'detached'
#GEKKO model and initialise model simulator
m = GEKKO(remote=False); m.options.IMODE=4

T_int = m.FV(295, lb=18+273.15, ub=24+273.15)
T_wal = m.FV(295, lb=15+273.15, ub=30+273.15)

# building coefficients
R_int, C_int, R_wal, C_wal, gA = build_type[btype]
# Matrix equations
A = np.array([[-1/(R_int*C_int), 1/(R_int*C_int)],
              [-1/(R_int*C_wal), -(-1/(R_wal*C_wal)-1/(R_int*C_wal))]])
Bc = 1/C_int
Bx = np.array([[0, gA/C_int, 1/C_int],
              [1/(R_wal*C_wal), 0, 0]])
C = np.array([[1, 0]])
# State Space
x, y, u = m.state_space(A,Bx,C,D=None,discrete=True)
# right now does not include Bc, could append into matrix Bx
Ta,Ih,Qo = u
# Building temperature variables
T_int,T_wal = x
T_int.value = 295
T_wal.value = 295

# Bounds on states can make the problem infeasible
#T_int.lower = 18+273.15
#T_int.upper = 24+273.15
#T_wal.lower = 15+273.15
#T_wal.upper = 30+273.15

# steady-state initialization
#m.options.IMODE = 1 
#m.solve() # (GUI=True)

# dynamic simulation
m.time = df['time'] # time points
m.options.nodes = 2 # must be 2 for discrete models
Ta.value = df["Ta"] # Ambient temp
Ih.value = df["Ih"] # Solar radiation
Qo.value = df["Qo"] # Additional heating influences
m.solve()
```

There are [additional state space examples](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/LinearStateSpace) in the documentation, including a complete [MPC application with an Arduino microcontroller](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/AdvancedTemperatureControl).